# Active Admin - Devise email translation

Tags: email, devise, translation, activeadmin

I am trying to translate the e-mail body of the activation, etc. emails that devise sends out for Active Admin admin_user, but in the devise.local.yml file I couldn't find where it is. I've only found the subject translations.

Where can I find it?

Best Wishes,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

First you have to take the add the devise translation (https://github.com/tigrish/devise-i18n/tree/master/config/locales) into the language.yml file, check the structure is maintained after insertion:

```
#config/locales/language.yml
<language>:
    devise:
        :<blah>...
```

After that you have to make the views for project and mails as follows:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

Edit the views in app/views/mailer

Good luck!